# Is there an easy way of locating a particular table when using the dbml design view in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

If you have a load of tables in your design view, its hard to find a particular one, is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the Properties window visible when the dbml file is open, simply navigate the tables using the dropdown menu at the top of the Properties window.

[image]